# Xamarin Calling a TabbedPage using a Button

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I want to load a TabbedPage when I click on a button in a different page, so I created this code:

```
protected void imgAdd_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var tabbedPage = new TabbedPage();
    tabbedPage.Children.Add(new Page1());
    tabbedPage.Children.Add(new Page2());

    App.Current.MainPage = tabbedPage;
}
```

But the result is as follows:
[image]

As you can see the Image leaves a trail of the image when you swipe between the pages.

However, when I load the Tabbed Page using the App.xaml.cs it loads correctly without the flickering, so it seems to only occur when I call the tabbed page from another page...

Any ideas?

Comment: First of all , remove this line: App.Current.MainPage = new TabbedPage(); 
Not sure,may be this is the culprit

Comment: Removed it, but still same result!

Comment: Show us Page1 and Page2 .
Are the images you are using big in size ? use small images and check again

Comment: Still no luck!!

Comment: I make the sample to test, do not reproduce the error. Maybe i miss something, you could check the sample `TabbedPageDemo` on my github with 3.gif.https://github.com/WendyZang/Test

Comment: Have you check the sample in my previous comment?

Comment: Sorry, was busy with other apps, but just checked it and it worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make the sample to test. You could check the sample `TabbedPageDemo` on my github.
https://github.com/WendyZang/Test.git

Create two pages.

Page1.xaml:

```
<StackLayout >
        <Image Source="pig.jpg"></Image>
    </StackLayout>
```

Page2.xaml:

```
<StackLayout>
        <Image Source="world.jpg"></Image>
    </StackLayout>
```

With the code you provided.

```
  var tabbedPage = new TabbedPage();
        tabbedPage.Children.Add(new Page1());
        tabbedPage.Children.Add(new Page2());
 App.Current.MainPage = tabbedPage;
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Need more explanation about the issue,

The tabs in the Tabbedpage are dynamically created?

Suggestion: Use https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/tabbed-view/getting-started

it will save your time.

Comment: How do you mean: "More explanation"? I have added an image of the problem. The images multiply a lot when you swipe left/right!