# Xamarin Create square layout using screen size

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I want to create a StackLayout that has the width and height of the screen size, so it will be a square. I already tried this:

```
public Page1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    imageLayout.HeightRequest = Application.Current.MainPage.Width;
    imageLayout.WidthRequest = Application.Current.MainPage.Width;
}
```

But that gave me the error that `Application.Current.MainPage` is null.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would use the SizeChanged Event from your page:

```
public Page1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    SizeChanged += (s,a) =>
    {
        imageLayout.HeightRequest = this.Width;
        imageLayout.WidthRequest = this.Width;
    };

}
```

Comment: And put that just below the InitializeComponent();?

Comment: Could you please check his question as well ? :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58997167/xamarin-image-flickering-in-tabbed-page

Answer (score 1):

You should override `OnSizeAllocated` for these purposes.

```
protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
    {
        base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);
        imageLayout.WidthRequest= width;
        imageLayout.HeightRequest = width;
    }
```

Much cleaner way